# Parameter Variation: Tracking the Metadata

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to use parameter variation in AnyLogic. My inputs are 3 parameters, each varying 5 times. My output is water demand. What I need from parameter variation is the way in which demand changes according to the different combinations of the three parameters. I imagine something like: there are 10,950 rows (one for each day), the first column is time (in days), the second column are the values for the first combination, the second column is the second combination, and so on and so forth. What would be the best way to track this metadata to then be able to export it to excel? I have added a "dataset" to my main to track demand through each simulation, but I am not sure what to add to the parameter variation experiment interface to track the output across the different iterations. It would also be helpful to have a way to know which combination of inputs produced a given output (for example, have the combination be the name for each column). I see that there are Java Actions, but I haven't been able to figure out the code to do what I need. I appreciate any help with this matter.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is just to track this in output database tables which are then exported to Excel at the end of your run. As long as these tables include outputs from multiple runs (and are, for example, only cleared at the start of the *experiment* not the *run*), your Parameter Variation experiment will end up with an Excel file having outcomes from all the runs. (You will probably need to turn off parallel execution in the PV experiment so you don't run into issues trying to write to the same Excel file in parallel.)

So, for example, you might have tables:

- `run_details` with columns `id`, `parm1`, `parm2` and `parm3` (with proper column names given your actual parameters and some unique ID generated for each run)
- `output_demand` with columns `run_id`, `sim_time_hrs` and `demand_value` (if, say, you're storing some demand value each hour of simulated time) where `run_id` cross-references the run's ID in `run_details`

(There is extra complexity in how you could allocate a unique run ID and how and when you write to/clear those tables, but I'm just presenting the core design. You can also get round the need-serial-execution point by programmatically controlling when you export to Excel, rather than using the built-in "Export tables at the end of model execution" capability, but that's also more complicated.)